# Create new TFS 2015 team project collection using blank database (permissions related)

Tags: tfs

I need to create a new team project collection in TFS 2015 Update 3 and I'm following [this guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/manage-team-project-collections#create-a-team-project-collection).

Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent service account does not have the privilege to create databases on the DB server, and I intend to keep like this. 
For this I consider:

1. DBA create empty database named appropriately but assign no permissions for the Team Foundation Background service account
2. Run “Use this existing database” in the Create Team Project Collection wizard.

I assume this will create necessary schemas/metadata in DB and allow TFSExecRole to the Team Foundation Background Job Agent service account on this new database.

Question: Is this correct?

Comment: @drhorgan Which account are you using to create the new collection? Team Foundation Background service account? Is the account an administrator on the servers? If not, then you can not create the collection. Just try to [Add administrators to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/add-administrator-tfs). Even if you create empty database, you also need to grant the connect permission at least for the users. Please share the logs here for troubleshoot.

Comment: As I understood in documentation from original thread, the collection database creation is done using the Team Foundation Background service account permissions not my account. Presently the Team Foundation Background service account is member of the TFS Administrators group but not a local admin on the TFS box. I did not run the project collection creation yet therefore do not have logs. 
The documentation above specifies for my user to have write permissions to this new database,should be db_owner permissions for the Team Foundation service account which runs the database altering scripts

Comment: Please let me know if my note above looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you mentioned the `Team Foundation Background service account` should be the account which you specified to connect to the SQL Server during the TFS configuration.

You will find that the owner of the collection DB should be the user who created the collection (Right click the collection DB -> Properties -> General).

Actually, all the TFS Administrators ([Add administrators to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/add-administrator-tfs)) are the owner of the collection DBs (Security -> Logins -> Right click on any admin users -> properties -> User Mapping ).

So, whatever you need to use the TFS administrators account to create the NEW Collection. Just exactly following the guides: [Create a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/manage-team-project-collections#create-a-team-project-collection)

[image]

Comment: I think what you mean is ask DBA to create empty database and assign db_owner for the TFS Service and input this database name into the “Use this existing database” in the Create Team Project Collection wizard (since TFSExecRole role would not exist into an empty database but will be created by the TFS service new team project collection script)

Comment: @drhorg Yes, you can have a try, I tested with “Use this existing database” which created by DBA, it works on my side. But the pre-requisite is that the account which you want to use to create the collection is the tfs administrtor account.